# Setting up an In memory mongoDB for testing with Jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, testing, mocking, ts-jest

I'm looking to set up a few tests with jest which requires me to have an in-memory MongoDB running for the tests to use. The way I'm looking at doing this is by creating a helper function that sets up my database connection normally outside of tests. But I can't seem to mock it and replace it with a mock implementation successfully. It keeps trying to use the actual database instead of the in-memory one I'm trying to use.

This is what my support function looks like:

```
export const databaseConnection = async () => {
  const client = await connect();
  const database = process.env.DATABASE_NAME;
  const collection = client.db(database).collection('collectionName');

  return collection;
};
```

I want to replace that to instead look like this:

```
export const databaseConnection = async () => {
  const client = await inMemoryConnect();
  const database = process.env.DATABASE_NAME;
  const collection = client.db(database).collection('collectionName');

  return collection;
};
```

The way I have been trying to set it up to replace the implementation has been by doing this:

```
jest.fn(databaseConnection).mockImplementation(async () => {
  const client = await inMemoryConnect();
  const database = process.env.DATABASE_NAME;
  const clubhouseCollection = client.db(database).collection('clubhouse');

  return clubhouseCollection;
});
```

But this mock in my test won't replace the one in the actual function I'm testing and instead keeps using the real database connection instead of my in-memory one. I can replace the inMemoryConnect in the non-mocked dataConnection and it'll use the in-memory database there. Just in my tests, it won't work. What could I be doing that is causing this to not correctly mock the function implementation?